# normalizing my timeseries dataset then setting the timestamp as Index

Tags: python, pandas, normalization

here is my code trying to normalize my dataset, the code works but the problem is when I create the new data frame (the last line of my code) it is not including the timestamp column because it is just including the scaled values.

```
data_consumption2 = pd.read_excel(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Thesis\Tarek\Parent.xlsx", sheet_name="Consumption")
data_consumption2['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(data_consumption2['Timestamp'], unit='s')
data_consumption2.fillna(0,inplace=True)
data_consumption2 = data_consumption2.set_index('Timestamp')
#returns a numpy array

min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(data_consumption2.values)
data_consumption2 = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
```

I hope any one can help me with having my original dframe with timestamps and scaled values in it

Comment: [tag:database-normalization] is about normalizing tables, not data sets that happen to be stored in a DB. Add tags by clicking on them & read the wikis.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For R/SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Stop trying to code your overall goal & explain what you expected instead from the given code & why.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the index of the new dataframe you created.

What the `min_max_scaler.fit_transform` returns is a numpy array of the scaled values (thus losing the index).

So you could do :

```
data_consumption2 = pd.DataFrame(data=x_scaled, index=data_consumption2.index)
```

If you want to also retrieve the columns, you can also pass them along :

```
data_consumption2 = pd.DataFrame(data=x_scaled,
                                 index=data_consumption2.index, 
                                 columns=data_consumption2.columns)
```

More details in the `DataFrame`'s documentation : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html

Those are basic pandas' manipulations, you should find all the answers about it in their documentation.

Comment: thanks a lot that works, what if I wanna restore the original columns names as well?

Comment: I edited the answer with additional info on that, please don't deviate too much from the original question :)